# ASP.Net Core returns a 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR from a FileStreamResult

Tags: asp.net-core, exception, filestream, memorystream

ASP.Net Core returns a 500 server error from a FileStreamResult when using MemoryStream to write into PDF

```
public async Task <Stream> DownloadDocumentInfoAsPdfAsync(User loggedInUser) {
    try {
        var conversionOptions = new ConversionOptions {
            Margins = new MarginSettings(20, 5.5, 10, 5.5),
        };

        //Creating new MemoryStream from byte[]
        return new MemoryStream(_htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertHtml(html, conversionOptions));
    }
}

//Returning FileStream from above function.
public async Task <IActionResult> GenerateReport([FromRoute] string info) {
    var result = await _mediator.Send(query);
    return File(result, "application/pdf", "employee.pdf"); //This will through 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
}
```

Comment: Share the stacktrace?

Comment: If you are going to be answering your own questions, please use the "Answer your own question" checkbox while entering the question.

Comment: @gldraphael: please donot close the post without understanding the implementation.Donot close the posts only for sake of closing.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're telling me that. I din't cast a close vote. Besides, since you seem to have already found the answer, whether its closed or open shouldn't matter. Closing just means the question won't get new answers from others; see https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions. Others can still vote.

Comment: @gldraphael: this is a real-time issue faced by developers.If the issue is not faced by you during conversion of stream, it doesn't mean the answer i gave is of no use.Please consider the issue.

Comment: Thank you for this question. It helped me to realize what I've been doing wrong in a situation where .NET Core returned an error 500 WITHOUT throwing an exception that I could catch, basically leaving me with nothing to investigate...

Comment: The only way I was able to see the 500 exception was by looking at the post call to my controller that my javascript was doing.  So looking at the dev tools Network tab, and viewing the post request I saw the response was 500.  The problem with my controller was I was using `return View(viewModel);` but for some reason this was causing a 500 error and I have no idea why because the controller matched the view name.  I had to change it to `return View("path to.cshtml", viewModel);` and the error went away.  This was in .net 6

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you have verified that the stream you created is valid there is a good chance that the position of the stream has not been reset to the start of the stream. The result of this is that the FileStreamResult tries to create a stream but starts from it's end position and finds no additional data and thus tries to write a blank stream out which is the cause of the error (this is not thrown as an Exception).

The fix this problem you will want to reset the stream you're using to it's start position.  The result.Position = 0; line then resets the MemoryStream before it is written out to the FileStreamResult.

```
// Reset the position on the MemoryStream to the beginning in IActionResult() function before returing FileStream

result.Position = 0;
//return File(result,"application/pdf","Employee.pdf")
```

Comment: Hitting the exact same problem, thansk for the answer and explanation.